# How to display collapse when checkbox clicked in Ember bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm fairly new to Ember and I'm trying to implement a Collapse method when I have clicked on a checkbox as a part of my form. This checkbox is inside a collapsed section part of a button group I have in my form.

**Template.hbs**

```
      {{#bs-button onClick=(action "toggle")}}
        {{#if collapsed}}
          {{form.element controlType="checkbox" label="View Additional Fields" property="additionalFields"}}
        {{/if}}
        <div>
          {{#bs-collapse collapsed=collapsed}}
            {{form.element controlType="checkbox" label="Property" property="property"}}
            {{form.element controlType="textarea" label="Instructions:" name="instructions" property="instructions"}}
          {{/bs-collapse}}
        </div>
      {{/bs-button}}
```

**Component.js**

```
collapsed: true,
actions: {
toggle() {
  let toggleValue = !get(this, 'collapsed');
  set(this, 'collapsed', toggleValue);
  }
}
```

When running ember serve and I go to my form if I click on the checkbox an error pops up in Ember Inspector:

> Assertion Failed: You cannot use the form element's default onChange action for form elements if not using a model or setting the value directly on a form element. 
>   You must add your own onChange action to the form element in this case! 
>   Error

If I change onClick to onChange then fields aren't displayed when I click the checkbox, but I still get the error. What would be the best way to go about trying to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing has nothing to do with `{{bs-collapse}}` or your `{{bs-button}}` `onClick` action. It seems like your `{{bs-form}}` does not have a `model` property but [ember-bootstrap](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) requires that one if you don't that an `onChange` action to each `{{form.element}}`. You find details in [ember-bootstrap api docs](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Form.html) and in [source code](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/files/addon_components_base_bs-form.js.html#263).